# How to use parsley validation for angular2 custom tags

Tags: parsley.js

I am using ng2-select2 along with parsleyjs. The field is mandatory field and looks something like as below

```
<select2 (valueChanged)="valueChange($event)" [value]="initialValues" [data]="data" [options]="options" required data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-required-message="Required Field" ngDefaultControl > </select2>
```

---

But, even after properly initializing select2 and checking validations using method jQuery('#' + this.formHtmlId).parsley().isValid() 
The validations for select2 is not getting trigger. But the same configuration works for html5 tags like input or text area. Is it possible that parsley is having issue with these kind of custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how angular does `select2`, but it's likely, it inserts a hidden field to hold the actual value. By default, `input[type=hidden]` is in the `excluded` preference, so you'll have to tweak that.